# Max number of tables in an Sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been researching how many different tables and schemas I can put into a single sql server database, but I keep running into the following phrase:

> Limited by number of objects in a database

But when I research the max number of objects in a database, I am unable to find a clear definition of this limitation.

Any ideas?

Comment: `select * from sys.objects`

Comment: my question is more about the "potential" not the current count. I.E. If I filled a databases sys.objects table, what would "select count(*) from sys.objects" return?

Comment: sounds like you are just asking this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786392/max-number-of-tables-objects-in-sql-server-editions-compact-express

Comment: ha! thanks, I think I was just not asking the correct question.
thank you @KHeaney!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: WAY more than you should ever have. If you are truly concerned that you might be running out of objects you need to redesign nearly everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fine note at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.110).aspx):

> 3 - Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored
>   procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and
>   constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot
>   exceed 2,147,483,647.

So 2^31 - 1 it is.